# How can I make a batch script copy files from the user folder with support for different users?

Tags: batch-file, onedrive

I would like to use a short batch script to copy files from OneDrive to a different folder, the issue is the OneDrive folder is in the users folder under C:/.

What can I do to have the batch script go into the user folder of the user currently logged in followed by the OneDrive folder to copy a specific file?

**Currently this is what I have:**

```
xcopy "C:\jmills\OneDrive\TestFolder\Test_2018.accde" "C:\Test\Test_EXE\" /d
```

As you can see the user "jmills" is hard coded which makes the batch work with only this specific user.

Comment: The currently logged in user is an [environmental variable](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) named username. Type `SET` at a command prompt to see all the current system variables you can use.

Comment: I see, so instead of "jmills" I write {username} or USERNAME

Comment: I see you didn't read the first couple of lines of the link I posted. **Variables have a percent sign on both sides: %ThisIsAVariable%**

Comment: Correct, but in one of the examples it shows: C:\Users\{Username}\AppData\Local\Temp

Comment: Where username is written as {Username} not with %

Comment: Feel free to interpret and use what you want. I can guarantee that your interpretation will not work.

Comment: You were absolutely correct, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is hardcoded because you selected to hardcode it. Note that there is an environment variable called `username` which holds the username of the user currently logged in. Variables in batch file can be accessed by `%` or `!` when delayed expansion is enabled. I find no reason for using delayed expansion here, so use just percent-signs:

```bat
xcopy "C:\%username%\OneDrive\TestFolder\Test_2018.accde" "C:\Test\Test_EXE\" /d
```